# Calculating the Big-O of a method

Tags: java, analytics

I'm struggling to figure out the O(g(n)) of this algorithm

```
int a = 1;
for (int i = 0; i< n*n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        if (a <= j) {
            a = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yshavit Well technically, we can answer this question. n times n is a constant and there are two for loops both bounded by "n times n". I think it's pretty obvious what the answer is, but this also seems like homework so I'll leave that as hint enough.

Comment: @yshavit Actually, no, we can't

Comment: @yshavit We can't answer the question.

Comment: @yshavit My fault. It was KyleM who said "Well technically, we can answer this question" and that's not true. I apologize.

Comment: Well what i don't understand is how is isn't the nested for loop n^3 and you can derive the rest of the equation with that?

Comment: Better yet how do you find the running time of this algorithm for the worst case

Answer (score 3):

When you have a loop nest like this, it's often helpful to work from the inside out. Notice, for example, that the innermost loop runs Θ(i) times. So, in a sense, the question boils down to determining the work done by this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
    do Theta(i) units of work
}
```

The work done here is proportional to

> 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n<sup>2</sup> - 1

We can simplify this by using [Gauss's sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum):

> 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n<sup>2</sup> - 1 = n<sup>2</sup>(n<sup>2</sup> - 1) / 2

This final expression is Θ(n<sup>4</sup>) because it's the product of two quadratic terms. So, overall, the work done is Θ(n<sup>4</sup>).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 1;
for (int i = 0; i< n*n; i++) { //Complexity n*n
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { //Complexty n*n 
        if (a <= j) {
            a = i;
        }
    }
}
```

O(n) = (n*n) * (n*n) = n^4 roughly